# linq query with reflection like method (making the method allow dynamic inputs for queries)

Tags: c#, linq, google-sheets, gdata, google-sheets-api

pardon my lack of knowledge with programming terms, hope this question title fits what the tasks at hand is about.

any particular way to make reflection works for a method like this particularly for the t.AsQueryable() with the where/orderby ?

example code (working but anyway to utilize the method inputs and use reflection to  allow dynamic inputs?)

```
public void searchField(string inputSearchColumnName, string inputSearchColumnValue, string orderByColumnName)
{
    var client = new DatabaseClient(this.userID, this.password); // login with id and password
    string dbName = this.dbName; // dbName is spreadsheet name
    var db = client.GetDatabase(dbName) ?? client.CreateDatabase(dbName); // execute the database command to either open the database or create the database if it does not exist
    string tableName = this.tableName; // tableName is the sheet name
    var t = db.GetTable<Entity>(tableName) ?? db.CreateTable<Entity>(tableName); // open the sheet name or create the sheet if it does not exist

    var rows = from e in t.AsQueryable()
               where e.QRCodeNumber == "QR987458789"
               orderby e.LastModifiedDateTime
               select e;

    //Console.WriteLine("{0} elements found", rows.ToList().Count());
    process_status += "</br>" + "{0} elements found" + rows.ToList().Count();
    process_status += "the record is: " + rows.ToList().ElementAt(0).LastModifiedDateTime;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to use reflection api in above code?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want to look into Expressions

Comment: it is to be used with GBDataDB, and GDataDB.linq   (basically it is google-spreadsheet api library)

Answer (score 1):

To construct dynamic queries, you can use the `System.Linq.Dynamic` library like this:

```
myContext.SomeEntity.Where(myWhereString).OrderBy(myOrderByString).ToArray();
```

Check the [dynamic linq documentation](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation) for more information